# Ubuntu doesn't translate /home/testuser to ~

Tags: bash, ubuntu, home, ldap, tilde

In Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, if I log in with the credentials of the LDAP user `testuser`, in several different programs the path of the `$HOME` directory is not replaced by `~` (as instead it happens for local users).

A couple of examples:

1. In `bash`, the value of `PS1` is the default one:

   ```
   \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
   ```

but it appears as

```
testuser@myhost:/home/testuser$
```

instead of

```
testuser@myhost:~$
```

2. In `neomutt`, in the left column where the mail directories are listed, their full path appears

   ```
   /home/testuser/Mail/mailbox1
   ```

instead of

```
   ~/Mail/mailbox1
```

However, in `bash`,

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/testuser
```

so the `env` variable `HOME` is somewhat recognized.

What could it be the problem?

---

**Update**

I am using `sssd` to manage the authentication of the LDAP users:

```
$ grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf 
passwd:         files systemd sss
```

The entries of the LDAP user and of a local user look very similar:

```
$ getent passwd testuser
testuser:*:<uid>:<gid>:Test User:/home/testuser/:/usr/bin/bash

$ getent passwd localuser
localuser:x:<uid>:<gid>:,,,:/home/localuser:/bin/bash
```

And

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/testuser/
```

matches the home directory specified in `getent passwd testuser`.

Comment: If you run `getent passwd testuser`, will you get a line resembling a normal `/etc/passwd` line but describing the LDAP user? If not, what is the output of `grep passwd: /etc/nsswitch.conf`? Does the home directory listed in `getent passwd testuser` output match the value of `$HOME`?

Comment: @telcoM I edited the question with the output of the commands you mentioned.

Comment: Are you positive this is not a [Bash Prompt Special Character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) issue?

Comment: @eyoung100 No, because this issue does not regard only `bash`, but also other programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there is an extra slash at the end of the directory path in the LDAP record for the user's home directory, i.e.

```
/home/testuser/
```

instead of

```
/home/testuser
```

Yes, it is common to add a slash at the end of the directory name to indicate that it is in fact a directory, but that is just extra decoration for the user, not the standard form of the pathname.

For example, the `pwd` command returns the current working directory without appending a slash, basically because that is how it is returned by the `getcwd()` system/libc call, as required by POSIX compliance. **The home directory pathname stored in the user record, whether in `/etc/passwd` or in LDAP, is expected to be in the same format.** This allows the replacement of the home directory path by `~` with a simple string comparison and replacement operation.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the trailing `/` character in the LDAP definition of `$HOME`:

> ```
> getent passwd testuser
> testuser:*:<uid>:<gid>:Test User:/home/testuser/:/usr/bin/bash
> ```

You can demonstrate this with your local user account:

```
OHOME="$HOME"
cd "$HOME"

HOME="$HOME/"
cd "$HOME"

HOME="$OHOME"
[ -n "$OHOME" ] && { HOME="$OHOME"; unset OHOME; }
```

You'll see that once you've assigned `HOME="$HOME/"` the `~` swaps to an absolute path for your home directory.